# Is there a way to exclude the results of psql query that matches a specific comment in the query?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to exclude the results of a query that match a comment?
For instance, if I have a comment called "foobar", and I want to exclude it from the results, is something like this possible?

```
SELECT /* foobar */
*
FROM
pg_stat_activity
AND
query NOT LIKE '%foobar%'
```

BTW, that does not work, but maybe there is a way?

Comment: What's wrong with `query NOT LIKE '%foobar%'` as you have done

Comment: WHERE query NOT LIKE

Comment: it does not work as I have it because if I change the comment of the query to "foo2bar", it doesn't change the results.  It seems like "query NOT LIKE" really means "close enough" and not "exact match".